# Power BI Embedded with validations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, azure, powerbi-embedded

Background:

In one Web application of ours, which is authenticated we have links to download a PBIX files. The idea was to provide a Power BI report which the user can download and open with Power BI desktop.

Once downloaded, the user can then click on "Refresh", which will prompt the user for user credentials. The user get authenticated, the Report is then rendered with data available to the user. This was all handled via Desktop.
The connection is via an authenticated OData service.

Now, our intention is to say "embed" a report, such that the user does not have to download the report, rather can see the report on a page of web application.

The users that we have do not come along with any Azure or Power BI subscription of their own.

While trying out the embedded option, I provisioned the workspace and imported the report. I used that report to embed and run across following problems:

1. The report does render but the data that is visible is that of the user who "imported" the report. i.e. my account & not the logged in user
2. I looked at various QueryString or parameters for the Embedded but could not find a way to pass on the credentials or user information for querying user specific data
3. I could not see an option to customize the DataSet before import such that the imported PBIX is just a template or Structure instead of Structure + Data.

**Question**: what is the way to embed a Power BI report in a web application so that the authenticated user can see specific data? I could not find any resource.

Also, if not embedded, what is another way of supporting such basic requirement of showing a report in web application

I also explored if I can use Direct Query instead of OData service, but basic requirement of sending credentials or user information still stays.

I will be great if someone can point me to a solution about how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

1. I updated the NuGet package for Power BI
2. Followed the steps [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-rls/)
3. Then in code, I passed on the username from this constructor: PowerBIToken.CreateReportEmbedToken()